A word to describe somebody who farts all the time
Is there a word to describe somebody who farts all the time?
Oh and for somebody whose fart stinks the whole universe as well.
I really need these to talk about my grandpa.

Where is your research? Try: passing gas.

Ole Grandpa... he loves cutting the cheese

I thought there was an age limit of 13 or over on this site.

@MichaelHarvey People often see anything related to fart as a joke, but well, it is a normal occurrence and non-native speakers might want to talk about it, when need be, just as much as native speakers do, don't they?

@Lambie isn't passing gas just a polite way to say fart?

Hold on. Am I not taken seriously because "fart" is not an appropriate term in English? If that's the case, I had no idea. Before reading the phrase "passing gas", I'd known only one way to describe the action, which is "fart".

So, describe it medically, instead of the person: https://www.healthline.com/health/gas-flatulence#causes

Not at all. In English, we'd just say a farter. But I doubt you want to say that to your grandad directly.

I seem to recall being told that finding farting funny is one of the very few characteristics that all humans have in common. Perhaps instead of the United Nations we should have United Flatulents!

Daft question.  A person who farts a lot is  "a person who farts a lot"   a person whose farts smell bad is "a person whose farts smell bad".  no need for anything more than that.

In English, we don't usually go around qualifying the person as a farter, just the thing itself. Unless you want to make it baby-talk.

The adjective to describe a person with such a condition is flatulent:

ADJECTIVE


suffering from or caused by an excessive amount of gas in the alimentary canal, producing uncomfortable distension
generating excessive gas in the alimentary canal

EDIT
I add to what @FumbleFingers said.
There may not be definitions for flatulent as a noun.  Usage of the word as a norminalised adjective, however, could be found in the full OED, which cited it in 1858:

The dyspeptic, the flatulent, and the sedentary.

As the usage of this word as a noun is so rare, I will use it if at all as an adjective rather than a noun.

“Excuse the smell that's my flatulent grandpa" Maybe…?

Thanks, @Mari-Lou A.  That's possible.

I was disappointed to find that the full OED only defines flatulent as an adjective, so you can't say "He is a flatulent". But they do list it as an "absolute" term, similar to The poor are always with us, with their 1858 cite: The dyspeptic, the flatulent, and the sedentary.

Thanks, @FumbleFingers.  I have incorporated your points into my answer.

The term fart is a flexible one. It can be a verb, Who farted? It can be a noun, they bought a fart bomb while the noun phrase an old fart, is used for people more advanced in their years. The derogatory phrase means an old fashioned person, behind with the times, whose  opinion is not valued.
The adjective farty in the sobriquet farty pants,  suggests someone who frequently breaks wind in their underwear (UK). There is even a British children's book entitled Granny Farty Pants

So, if the OP really must give an English nickname to his grandpa, it could be “Gramps Farty Pants”, "old fart", "farty Grandpa” or "ripping Grandpop” which sounds kind of cool but really means a farting grandaddy.
Ah, yes, with the exception of "farty" these suggestions are longer than one word and the OP asked for a single word. Maybe there is one out there but I don't think there is a single word meaning someone who continually breaks wind and whose smell is particularly pungent.
